# How to alter external table in Redshift Spectrum?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I want to add a partition of data to my external table, but I'm receiving the error: ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE cannot run inside a transaction block.

I removed the BEGIN/END transaction but still the same error persists. I read on some forums that adding an isolation level might solve the problem, but wanted to get an opinion of others, if someone has experienced this before.

Comment: you probably need the transaction commit mode to be "auto" rather than "manual". setting this depends on how you connect. using psql from command line is the safest way.

Comment: It would help if you can provide example code to reproduce the error and also explain what client tools & drivers you are using,

Comment: @JonScott Any code you can post for doing this from a psql client? I'm trying to do the same thing (e.g. I first use unload to write a table to s3 bucket) then try to partition the external table. The usual alter table command I use in my SQLworkbenchJ client gives me an error when I try to do the same command with psql client in crontab

Answer (score 0):

A standard statement like this works for me. If you are getting error from this as well, please share your exact statement ?

```
ALTER TABLE spectrum_schema.spect_test 
ADD PARTITION (column_part='2019-07-23') 
LOCATION 's3://bucketname/folder1/column_part=2019-07-23/';
```